# Split pages vertically with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible to split pages vertically using `wkhtmltopdf`? This would basically turn a single page into two pages.

I've drawn a little image, maybe that makes it a bit clearer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to face a similar issue in my project.

You have 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. One way is to solve it using CSS, however the version of webkit included in wkhtmltopdf (at least the stable version) seems to be a bit old and does not support CSS multi-columns directives very well, [see here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1872).

   For future reference I copy&paste the example template included in the linked issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: none;
            width: 17cm;
        }
        .container {
            /* You *must* define a fixed height which is
               large enough to fit the whole content,
               otherwise the layout is unpredictable. */
            height: 28em;
            /* Width and count aren't respected, but you
               have to give at least some dummy value (??). */
            -webkit-columns: 0 0;
            /* This is the strange way to define the number of columns:
               50% = 2 columns, 33% = 3 columns 25% = 4 columns */
            width: 33%; 
            /* Gap and rule do work. */
            -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
            -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
            text-align: justify;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>An Article</h1>
        <p>
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
        3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
        4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Another option (the one I ended up using) is to setup the layout of the page using a table with 2..n columns. You can then use a template engine or even JavaScript to fill the page with content and split the pages.

   This approach is simple and works well if the content in the page has predictable size, in fact you cannot rely on wkhtmltopdf for splitting the content into several pages, you must do it yourself with the code.

Approach 1) is quite buggy but might be worth a shot if you're dealing with text, which might not be very suitable for approach 2).

If your content is regular it will be reasonably easy to hop on approach 2) and lay down the elements and split the pages using the code.